# UnsatisfiedDependencyException because of the JDK proxy

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection, spring-aop

I'm trying to use the default aop proxy provided by Spring, but i'm getting an execption error.

Here is my code:
A first class that run the test example.

```
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy()
@ComponentScan(basePackageClasses = {MyDaoRepository.class, MyService.class,MyAdvices.class})
@Configuration
public class SpringAdvices {
   public static void main( String[] args ) {
        ApplicationContext ctx = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(SpringAdvices.class);
        service myService = ctx.getBean(MyService.class);
        Person p1 = (Person) ctx.getBean("person");
        myService.save(p1);

    }
     @Bean
     public Person person(){
            return Person.builder()
                    .name("Bagna")
                    .age(52)
                    .profession(null)
                    .dateOfBirth(LocalDate.of(1950,12,13))
                    .build();
        }
```

}

A second class that represent my advices:

```
@Aspect
@Component
public class MyAdvices {
    @Before("execution(boolean *.dao.save(..))")
    public void beforesavamethod(){
        System.out.println("beforesavamethod");
    }
    @After("execution(boolean *.dao.save(..))")
    public void aftersavamethod(){
        System.out.println("aftersavamethod");
    }
}
```

My service and repository classes:

```
@Service
public class MyService implements service {
    @Autowired
    MyDaoRepository myDaoRepository;

    @Override
    public boolean save( Person person ){
        return this.myDaoRepository.save(person);
    }
    @Override
    public boolean delete(Person person){
        return  this.myDaoRepository.delete(person);
    }
}

public interface service {
    public  boolean save( Person person );
    public  boolean delete( Person person );
}
@Repository
public class MyDaoRepository implements dao {
    List<Person> personList = new ArrayList<>();

    @Override
    public boolean save( Person person ){
        return this.personList.add(person);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean delete( Person person ){
        return  this.personList.remove(person);
    }
}
public interface dao {
    public boolean save( Person person );

    public boolean delete( Person person );
}
```

The exceptin I'm getting concern the injection of the dao object to the service object.

> UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name
>   'myService': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field
>   'myDaoRepository'; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanNotOfRequiredTypeException: Bean
>   named 'myDaoRepository' is expected to be of type
>   'aop.question_005.dao.MyDaoRepository' but was actually of type
>   'com.sun.proxy.$Proxy22'

I can solve this problem by enabling the GCLIB mechanism, but i'm wondering how can i solve this problem using the same JDK dynamic proxy?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem in your code is that you are using the class MyDaoRepository  instead of the  `dao` interface. You can cast your proxy to the interface dao but you can not cast it to its implementation. You need to modify your service code to use interfaces:

```
@Service
public class MyService implements service {
    @Autowired
    dao myDaoRepository;

    @Override
    public boolean save( Person person ){
        return this.myDaoRepository.save(person);
    }
    @Override
    public boolean delete(Person person){
        return  this.myDaoRepository.delete(person);
    }
}
```